# some questions about module and scripts

Tags: python, module

```
from bsm_functions import*
```

bsm_functions is a py document written by myself.It is "bsm_functions.py".It does not belong to the system.But when I write it directly,the error is:

```
No module named "bsm_functions"
```

Comment: Is it in the path? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960602/how-to-add-something-to-pythonpath